# Performing large queries on Array or DB in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, performance, optimization

Suppose I have an array of 10000 users, for each user I need to store 100 last actions they did, also the time of that action.

These data are stored on a mysql database too.
For every second, I need to check 100 user actions, It means I need to iterate all those 100 actions and time of actions for 100 users per minute.

So which one is faster? Query database 100 times per minute? or check those arrays 100 times.

What I'm asking here is, generally speaking, if you were in a situation where you need to perform large amount of database queries per second (100 per second) on a large amount of data (10000*200 = 2,000,000 records), you can also store that data in arrays and search in those arrays localy, which method will you pick? Also suppose both search in array and database are optimized methods. ( for example it's not bubble array sort and search ;) )

Comment: we can't tell. you'll have to benchmark it. e.g. what's the time for running 10,000 sql queries v.s. the time for loading/parsing/scanning arrays 10,000 times?

Comment: Is this a different question to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577604/100-queries-per-second-database-vs-array-in-php#comment49225469_30577604)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database connections are going to be the most expensive part of the algorithm, so minimize the amount of time each connection will last.

Pull it from the database and loop through the array.

Unless you are doing a function that would be very quick in a database (ie- sorting on an index, grouping, etc) you should do it in PHP

Comment: So 100 queries per second for database is not that bad?

Comment: @EBAG For lightweight queries it should not be a problem, but when you're comparing the cost of an algorithm you want to save resources wherever possible